# Dynamically added button omits confirm

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm developing a website for users where I add controls dynamically.

The problem is that after a confirmBox appears it doesn't matter what I click (Ok/Cancel) it still deletes my objects.

This is how I add them from codeBehind:

```
aPanel.RegisterAction("DeleteStuff", "Delete object", 
                            true, btnDeleteClick, null);
```

where aPanel is ActionPanelDx

right after this comes:

```
if (actionPanel["DeleteStuff"] != null)
    actionPanel["DeleteStuff"].ClientSideEvents.ItemClick = 
    "function(s,e){return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')}";

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, MenuItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Im using self written classes for handlig SQL logic it looks like this: 
    MySQLCommand commad = new MySQLCommand("delete_object");//procedure
    commad.MyParam.AddWithValue("@ob_id", ObjectID);
    commad.myExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Am I using the JS function in a wrong?

Comment: I believe in your deletion logic you don't check which button was pressed. It should be in `e` parameter

Comment: I added deletion logic, i have no idea how should it be handled here, and i have not found it anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now what your code does it to delete your object whenever a button (doesn't matter which) is clicked. What you need to do is something like that:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, MenuItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.item.name === "Yes")
    {
        MySQLCommand commad = new MySQLCommand("delete_object");//procedure
        commad.MyParam.AddWithValue("@ob_id", ObjectID);
        commad.myExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

instead of `e.item.name` it could be `e.item.text` or something like that, put a breakpoint or `console.log` to see what is inside of your `e` property if you not sure.